# How do I put numbers the right way around in Entry box using <entry_box_name>.insert

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I am currently developing a calculator app in Python where when you click a button, it enters the symbol on that button into the entry box displayed at the top of the window. However, when I click a number button - let's say I click the button with "4" on it, and then I click the button with "6" on it, the entry box shows the number 64, and not the number 46.

Here is the code for inserting the number 1 into the entry box (named user_output) when the "1" button is clicked:

```
def insert_one():
    user_output.insert(0, "1")
```

Here is what you'd get if you were to type in 563 into the calculator: http://prntscr.com/k7zugb

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** A user called Bryan Oakley asked for an illustration to show some of the code. Here is the demonstration so you can see how the code works when numbers are entered into user_output:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *

except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Demo")
window.geometry("323x75")

def insert_one():
    user_output.insert(0, "1")

def insert_two():
    user_output.insert(0, "2")

def insert_three():
    user_output.insert(0, "3")

user_output = Entry(width=53, justify=LEFT)
one = Button(text="1", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_one)
two = Button(text="2", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_two)
three = Button(text="3", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_three)

user_output.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
one.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
two.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
three.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question asks how to insert characters in front of previous characters. When you input 563 I would expect it to appear as 365 (insert 5, then 6 before 5, then 3 before 5) which is exactly what your picture shows. It looks like you already know exactly how to do what you're asking. Please create a [mcve] that illustrates your problem. It should only take a dozen lines of code or so.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, that's not what I mean. If I enter 563, it turns out to be 365, which is NOT what I want. If I type in 563, I expect it to turn out as 563, not 365.

Comment: Almost all references to the text widget will tell you that you can use the index `"end"` to insert characters at the end of the existing characters.

Comment: Try this: `user_output.insert("end", "1")`.

Comment: Mike SMT, thanks for the advice - the problem's fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solutions is to use the index "end" instead of zero.

You problem is how you are using insert. `user_output.insert(0, "1")`. Here you are imputing at the index of zero, in other words every time you press the button it will always insert the number at the front. Instead just used "end" for your index.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *

except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Demo")
window.geometry("323x75")

def insert_one():
    user_output.insert("end", "1")

def insert_two():
    user_output.insert("end", "2")

def insert_three():
    user_output.insert("end", "3")

user_output = Entry(width=53, justify=LEFT)
one = Button(text="1", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_one)
two = Button(text="2", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_two)
three = Button(text="3", height=3, width=2, justify=LEFT, command=insert_three)

user_output.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
one.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
two.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
three.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)

window.mainloop()
```